# loop to generate iterative rows of a matrix in mathematica

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I have a matrix

```
FT= {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1,
   2, 3}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 
  1, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 3,
   3}, {2, 4, 1}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 3}, {2, 5, 1}, {2, 5, 2}, {2, 5, 
  3}, {2, 6, 1}, {2, 6, 2}, {2, 6, 3}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 
  3}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 
  3}, {3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 3}, {3, 5, 1}, {3, 5, 2}, {3, 5, 
  3}, {3, 6, 1}, {3, 6, 2}, {3, 6, 3}, {3, 7, 1}, {3, 7, 2}, {3, 7, 
  3}, {3, 8, 1}, {3, 8, 2}, {3, 8, 3}, {3, 9, 1}, {3, 9, 2}, {3, 9, 
  3}, {3, 10, 1}, {3, 10, 2}, {3, 10, 3}, {3, 11, 1}, {3, 11, 2}, {3, 
  11, 3}, {3, 12, 1}, {3, 12, 2}, {3, 12, 3}}
```

Where each row represents a kind of address of each element whose first element gives G, second element gives B and the third element gives M. For e.g. for 3rd element G is 1, B is 1 and M is 2 and so on. Now i need to generate a matrix for each element such that whenever my G is 0 or 1 it gives me {0,0,0} and for G>1 it gives me rows with G-1, G-2 and so on till it gives 1; and for B it gives a check for whenever B is even it returns B/2 and whenever B is odd it returns (B+1) /2 and M takes value of 3 every time and finally a row {0,0,0}. For e.g. for last element with FT= {3,12,3} it should give me {{2,6,3}, {1,3,3}, {0,0,0}} and for `FT= {2,5,1}` it should give me `{{1,3,3}, {0,0,0}}`.
Can you please help me writing code for this in mathematica. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For this demo lower-case symbols are used to avoid conflicting with built-in functions, e.g. `D`, `E`, `I`, `N`

This function defines the basic operation

```
op[{g_, b_, m_}] := {g - 1, If[EvenQ[b], b/2, (b + 1)/2], 3}
```

which should be applied repeatedly until a condition is met.  `NestWhileList` is useful for this, e.g.

```
NestWhileList[op[#] &, {3, 12, 3}, First[#] > 1 &]
```

> {{3, 12, 3}, {2, 6, 3}, {1, 3, 3}}

Another function uses the above if `g > 1` :-

```
f[{g_, b_, m_}] := Append[
  If[g > 1, Rest@NestWhileList[op, {g, b, m}, First[#] > 1 &],
   {}], {0, 0, 0}]
```

E.g.

```
f[{2, 5, 1}]
```

> {{1, 3, 3}, {0, 0, 0}}

Now `f` can be mapped over `ft` :-

```
ft = {
   {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 1},
   {1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 3},
   {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2},
   {2, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3}, {2, 4, 1},
   {2, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 3}, {2, 5, 1}, {2, 5, 2}, {2, 5, 3},
   {2, 6, 1}, {2, 6, 2}, {2, 6, 3}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 2},
   {3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 1},
   {3, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 3},
   {3, 5, 1}, {3, 5, 2}, {3, 5, 3}, {3, 6, 1}, {3, 6, 2},
   {3, 6, 3}, {3, 7, 1}, {3, 7, 2}, {3, 7, 3}, {3, 8, 1},
   {3, 8, 2}, {3, 8, 3}, {3, 9, 1}, {3, 9, 2}, {3, 9, 3},
   {3, 10, 1}, {3, 10, 2}, {3, 10, 3}, {3, 11, 1}, {3, 11, 2},
   {3, 11, 3}, {3, 12, 1}, {3, 12, 2}, {3, 12, 3}};    

matrix = Map[f, ft]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now how can i get the intersection of any two elements of 'matrix'. I mean now i want a matrix that gives me intersection of two elements. For example matrix[[11]] is {{1, 1, 3}, {0, 0, 0}} and matrix[[30]] is {{2, 1, 3}, {1, 1, 3}, {0, 0, 0}}. So their intersection should give me {{1,1,3},{0,0,0}}. This i need a matrix inter[i_,j_] that gives me intersection of i and j elements of 'matrix'.

Comment: `inter[i_, j_] := Reverse[Intersection @@ matrix[[{i, j}]]]`